# Enabling mod_wsgi with SELinux (Is there a way?)

Tags: apache-2.2, deployment, httpd, mod-wsgi, selinux

I recently had a bit of problem when recently by Deploying Django with mod_wsgi due to SELinux. Usually world get a "Permission denied" error (403). This was solved by disabling SELinux.

Is there a way to use mod_wsgi while SELinux is enabled? Now if I was to move my djcode folder to /usr/local/ this would work, but if the djcode folder is stored /usr/local/src/djcode, it will give me again this error.

```
Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied
```

I have looked at some logs and it says this:

```
SElinux is preventing the httpd from using potentially mislabel files ./src (src_1)
```

So how would I allow the httpd use the src folder?

Comment: Someone wrote a guide to using SELinux with python web app's (w/ wsgi) here: http://www.packtpub.com/article/selinux-secured-web-hosting-python-based-web-applications